# Как реализовать обратный скролл страницы?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

коллеги.
Прошу вас посоветовать, как решить задачу:

САБЖ: Для ленда нужно реализовать прокрутку страницы Снизу-вверх.
Т.е. не сверху вниз, как обычно, а Начиная, как бы, с низу.
Стартует страница, как бы, с места футера, а скролиться вверх.

ПРОБЛЕМА:
При этом колесико мыши должно крутиться ОБРАТНО!

ИДЕЯ: Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.

Кто сталкивался с таким? Куда копать?

Comment: Юзвер крутить.)))

Comment: Мышь должна крутиться вниз, но при этом страница скролиться реверсивно, вверх? Если это так, то не советую так делать. Пользователя введёт это в ступор, первая мысль будет, что сайт неправильно работает. Учтите, что есть в интерфейсах и элементах управления уже давно устоявшиеся правила. Например - окно закрывается при нажатии на крестик, интерактивные объекты при наведении меняют курсор и внешний вид, при прокрутке вниз идёт скролл вниз. Нарушение таких правил ведёт к негативному пользовательскому опыту при работе с вашим интерфейсом.
Что касается самой реализации толком ничего не подскажу.

Comment: В том-то и дело, Денис, что Мышь должна крутиться ВВерх! А контент ИЗНАЧАЛЬНО быть какбы снизу, и крутиться тоже наверх

Comment: и в футере открывалась и скроллилась "наверх"... Клаву сломала, как ее отделать так...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5UUtV/1/

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy да я прост загуглил, да и твой круче

Comment: Направление прокрутки задом наперед уже реализовано в макоси. Посоветуйте юзерам смотреть сайт на "маках" =))) А если серьезно - руки надо отбивать за такие противоестественные решения. Надеюсь, что бредовейшую из бредовых  "идею" (`Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.`) вы не сами придумали, а это заказчик такой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инвертировать направление прокрутки мыши можно без скриптов всего несколькими строками css и двумя div'ами-контейнерами в разметке:

```css
html, body, .outer {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.outer {
  overflow: auto;
}

.outer, .inner {
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

/* Дальше просто укарашательство, к вопросу не относится */

body {
  counter-reset: i 0;
}

.post-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  counter-increment: i;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, antiquewhite);
}

.post-text > :first-child::before {
  content: "#" counter(i) " ";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
      <p>коллеги. Прошу вас посоветовать, как решить задачу:</p>
      <p>САБЖ: Для ленда нужно реализовать прокрутку страницы Снизу-вверх. Т.е. не сверху вниз, как обычно, а Начиная, как бы, с низу. Стартует страница, как бы, с места футера, а скролиться вверх.</p>
      <p>ПРОБЛЕМА: При этом колесико мыши должно крутиться ОБРАТНО!</p>
      <p>ИДЕЯ: Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.</p>
      <p>Кто сталкивался с таким? Куда копать?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
      <p>коллеги. Прошу вас посоветовать, как решить задачу:</p>
      <p>САБЖ: Для ленда нужно реализовать прокрутку страницы Снизу-вверх. Т.е. не сверху вниз, как обычно, а Начиная, как бы, с низу. Стартует страница, как бы, с места футера, а скролиться вверх.</p>
      <p>ПРОБЛЕМА: При этом колесико мыши должно крутиться ОБРАТНО!</p>
      <p>ИДЕЯ: Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.</p>
      <p>Кто сталкивался с таким? Куда копать?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
      <p>коллеги. Прошу вас посоветовать, как решить задачу:</p>
      <p>САБЖ: Для ленда нужно реализовать прокрутку страницы Снизу-вверх. Т.е. не сверху вниз, как обычно, а Начиная, как бы, с низу. Стартует страница, как бы, с места футера, а скролиться вверх.</p>
      <p>ПРОБЛЕМА: При этом колесико мыши должно крутиться ОБРАТНО!</p>
      <p>ИДЕЯ: Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.</p>
      <p>Кто сталкивался с таким? Куда копать?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
      <p>коллеги. Прошу вас посоветовать, как решить задачу:</p>
      <p>САБЖ: Для ленда нужно реализовать прокрутку страницы Снизу-вверх. Т.е. не сверху вниз, как обычно, а Начиная, как бы, с низу. Стартует страница, как бы, с места футера, а скролиться вверх.</p>
      <p>ПРОБЛЕМА: При этом колесико мыши должно крутиться ОБРАТНО!</p>
      <p>ИДЕЯ: Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.</p>
      <p>Кто сталкивался с таким? Куда копать?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
      <p>коллеги. Прошу вас посоветовать, как решить задачу:</p>
      <p>САБЖ: Для ленда нужно реализовать прокрутку страницы Снизу-вверх. Т.е. не сверху вниз, как обычно, а Начиная, как бы, с низу. Стартует страница, как бы, с места футера, а скролиться вверх.</p>
      <p>ПРОБЛЕМА: При этом колесико мыши должно крутиться ОБРАТНО!</p>
      <p>ИДЕЯ: Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.</p>
      <p>Кто сталкивался с таким? Куда копать?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
      <p>коллеги. Прошу вас посоветовать, как решить задачу:</p>
      <p>САБЖ: Для ленда нужно реализовать прокрутку страницы Снизу-вверх. Т.е. не сверху вниз, как обычно, а Начиная, как бы, с низу. Стартует страница, как бы, с места футера, а скролиться вверх.</p>
      <p>ПРОБЛЕМА: При этом колесико мыши должно крутиться ОБРАТНО!</p>
      <p>ИДЕЯ: Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.</p>
      <p>Кто сталкивался с таким? Куда копать?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
      <p>коллеги. Прошу вас посоветовать, как решить задачу:</p>
      <p>САБЖ: Для ленда нужно реализовать прокрутку страницы Снизу-вверх. Т.е. не сверху вниз, как обычно, а Начиная, как бы, с низу. Стартует страница, как бы, с места футера, а скролиться вверх.</p>
      <p>ПРОБЛЕМА: При этом колесико мыши должно крутиться ОБРАТНО!</p>
      <p>ИДЕЯ: Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.</p>
      <p>Кто сталкивался с таким? Куда копать?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
      <p>коллеги. Прошу вас посоветовать, как решить задачу:</p>
      <p>САБЖ: Для ленда нужно реализовать прокрутку страницы Снизу-вверх. Т.е. не сверху вниз, как обычно, а Начиная, как бы, с низу. Стартует страница, как бы, с места футера, а скролиться вверх.</p>
      <p>ПРОБЛЕМА: При этом колесико мыши должно крутиться ОБРАТНО!</p>
      <p>ИДЕЯ: Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.</p>
      <p>Кто сталкивался с таким? Куда копать?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
      <p>коллеги. Прошу вас посоветовать, как решить задачу:</p>
      <p>САБЖ: Для ленда нужно реализовать прокрутку страницы Снизу-вверх. Т.е. не сверху вниз, как обычно, а Начиная, как бы, с низу. Стартует страница, как бы, с места футера, а скролиться вверх.</p>
      <p>ПРОБЛЕМА: При этом колесико мыши должно крутиться ОБРАТНО!</p>
      <p>ИДЕЯ: Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.</p>
      <p>Кто сталкивался с таким? Куда копать?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="post-text" itemprop="text">
      <p>коллеги. Прошу вас посоветовать, как решить задачу:</p>
      <p>САБЖ: Для ленда нужно реализовать прокрутку страницы Снизу-вверх. Т.е. не сверху вниз, как обычно, а Начиная, как бы, с низу. Стартует страница, как бы, с места футера, а скролиться вверх.</p>
      <p>ПРОБЛЕМА: При этом колесико мыши должно крутиться ОБРАТНО!</p>
      <p>ИДЕЯ: Таким образом мы показываем юзеру, крутящему колесико мыши наверх, идею роста.</p>
      <p>Кто сталкивался с таким? Куда копать?</p>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Только вот в Firefox текст мыльный теперь)

Comment: Странно: на телефоне в хроме это работает только если развернуть на всю страницу

Comment: @andreymal, надо с высотами поиграться, чтобы дробное число пикселей не получалось. А вообще, я только в хроме проверял. На телефоне может iframe глючить, в котором пример отображается.

Answer (score 0):

```js
/* fork of https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar */
/* see lines: 39, 97, 119-121 */

;
(function(root, factory) {
  if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(window, document)
  } else {
    root.SimpleScrollbar = factory(window, document)
  }
})(this, function(w, d) {
  var raf = w.requestAnimationFrame || w.setImmediate || function(c) {
    return setTimeout(c, 0);
  };

  function initEl(el) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(el, 'data-simple-scrollbar')) return;
    Object.defineProperty(el, 'data-simple-scrollbar', {
      value: new SimpleScrollbar(el)
    });
  }

  // Mouse drag handler
  function dragDealer(el, context) {
    var lastPageY;

    el.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      lastPageY = e.pageY;
      el.classList.add('ss-grabbed');
      d.body.classList.add('ss-grabbed');

      d.addEventListener('mousemove', drag);
      d.addEventListener('mouseup', stop);

      return false;
    });

    function drag(e) {
      var delta = lastPageY - e.pageY;
      lastPageY = e.pageY;

      raf(function() {
        context.el.scrollTop += delta / context.scrollRatio;
      });
    }

    function stop() {
      el.classList.remove('ss-grabbed');
      d.body.classList.remove('ss-grabbed');
      d.removeEventListener('mousemove', drag);
      d.removeEventListener('mouseup', stop);
    }
  }

  // Constructor
  function ss(el) {
    this.target = el;

    this.direction = w.getComputedStyle(this.target).direction;

    this.bar = '<div class="ss-scroll">';

    this.wrapper = d.createElement('div');
    this.wrapper.setAttribute('class', 'ss-wrapper');

    this.el = d.createElement('div');
    this.el.setAttribute('class', 'ss-content');

    if (this.direction === 'rtl') {
      this.el.classList.add('rtl');
    }

    this.wrapper.appendChild(this.el);

    while (this.target.firstChild) {
      this.el.appendChild(this.target.firstChild);
    }
    this.target.appendChild(this.wrapper);

    this.target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.bar);
    this.bar = this.target.lastChild;

    dragDealer(this.bar, this);
    this.moveBar();

    w.addEventListener('resize', this.moveBar.bind(this));
    this.el.addEventListener('scroll', this.moveBar.bind(this));
    this.el.addEventListener('mouseenter', this.moveBar.bind(this));

    this.target.classList.add('ss-container');

    var css = w.getComputedStyle(el);
    if (css['height'] === '0px' && css['max-height'] !== '0px') {
      el.style.height = css['max-height'];
    }

    this.el.scrollTop = this.el.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight
  }

  ss.prototype = {
    moveBar: function(e) {
      var totalHeight = this.el.scrollHeight,
        ownHeight = this.el.clientHeight,
        _this = this;

      this.scrollRatio = ownHeight / totalHeight;

      var isRtl = _this.direction === 'rtl';
      var right = isRtl ?
        (_this.target.clientWidth - _this.bar.clientWidth + 18) :
        (_this.target.clientWidth - _this.bar.clientWidth) * -1;

      raf(function() {
        // Hide scrollbar if no scrolling is possible
        if (_this.scrollRatio >= 1) {
          _this.bar.classList.add('ss-hidden')
        } else {
          _this.bar.classList.remove('ss-hidden')
          const height = Math.max(_this.scrollRatio * 100, 10)
          const top = (100 - height) - (_this.el.scrollTop / totalHeight) * 100
          _this.bar.style.cssText = 'height:' + height + '%; top:' + top + '%;right:' + right + 'px;';
        }
      });
    }
  }

  function initAll() {
    var nodes = d.querySelectorAll('*[ss-container]');

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      initEl(nodes[i]);
    }
  }

  d.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', initAll);
  ss.initEl = initEl;
  ss.initAll = initAll;

  var SimpleScrollbar = ss;
  return SimpleScrollbar;
});

/* end fork */

SimpleScrollbar.initEl(document.body)
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}


#pane-1 {
  background-color: green;
}

#pane-2 {
  background-color: red;
}

#pane-3 {
  background-color: white;
}

#pane-4 {
  background-color: pink;
}

#pane-5 {
  background-color: yellow;
}




/* fork of https://github.com/buzinas/simple-scrollbar */

.ss-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}

.ss-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 18px);
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ss-content.rtl {
  width: calc(100% + 18px);
  right: auto;
}

.ss-scroll {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  width: 9px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
}

.ss-hidden {
  display: none;
}

.ss-container:hover .ss-scroll,
.ss-container:active .ss-scroll {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ss-grabbed {
  -o-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="panelCon">
    <div id="pane-5" class="panel">
      <h1>5</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pane-4" class="panel">
      <h1>4</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pane-3" class="panel">
      <h1>3</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pane-2" class="panel">
      <h1>2</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="pane-1" class="panel">
      <h1>1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Перенеси jsfiddle в сниппет. Ну, если это ответ, а не часть вопроса. Потому что на описание из вопроса не похоже.

Comment: @Qwertiy я так понял, что это ответ )

Comment: @Suvitruf, а где инвертирование направления прокрутки?

Comment: @Qwertiy эм. Кручу колёсико вверх, листается вниз и наоборот. Так же, как и в другом ответе. Или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: @Suvitruf, сравни с направлением прокрутки просто на странице. У меня по ощущениям как будто оно просто в конец проскроллено. Никакого инвертирования не вижу.

Comment: @Qwertiy хорошо бы ответ от топикстартера получить, а то я запутался D:

Comment: @Suvitruf, ага. Потому что вроде по тексту ответа говорится, что это решение, но реально что-то не похоже...